# Set custom log group for AWS Batch Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

I would like to programmatically determine, at runtime, the log-group where the logs from my Batch jobs are sent.
[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/using_awslogs.html) indicates that one can do so with a JSON object specifying:

```
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "awslogs-wordpress",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-example"
    }
}
```

However, the [syntax for submit_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.submit_job) seems to only allow string:string parameters to be sent to the job definition:

```
jobDefinition='string',
    parameters={
        'string': 'string'
    },
```

How do I send the nested LogConfiguration options into my submitted job?  My current command is:

```
response = client.submit_job(
        jobDefinition=job_def,
        jobName=options['file_suffix'],
        jobQueue='HLM2',
        arrayProperties={'size': job_array_size},
        tags={'OutputBucket': options['output_bucket'],
              'SubFolder': options['subfolder']},
        containerOverrides={
            'environment': [
                {
                    'name': 'COMMAND_FILE',
                    'value': file_key
                }
            ]
        },
        propagateTags=True)
```

If someone could provide a specific example of how to add the LogConfiguration override, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The log configuration you are trying to use applies only for job definitions, not for job invocations...

I could not find a simple way of overriding the metadata for logging like this. However, if you want to get the logging metadata from the container runtime, you could simply fetch them from the metadata URL provided as an environment variable (`$ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4`). There is a section called `LogOptions` that contains exactly what you need.
[Here is the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html).

If you use older container agent than 1.45.0 and you did not alter the defaults much, you can stitch the log stream together by compositing the `logStreamPrefix` with task ID, ie. if your prefix is xxx, then the stream would be called something like `xxx/default/<task_id>`

Hope this helps a little ☺️